# HTML buttons to filter elements; already have a functioning search bar

Tags: html, button, onclick, mean-stack

I am working on a web app that is to store sport cards, and we already have a functioning search bar. In order to make things easier on the user, we want to add buttons beneath the search bar that would filter the sport cards by their sport. While you could just search for "baseball" and it would accomplish the same thing... the client wants a specific look.

Here is our search bar:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="input-group" id="searchBar">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="query"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And our table:

```
<div class="grid-container">

                <div class="grid-item" ng-repeat="listing in listings | filter:query" >{{listing.playerName}}, {{listing.playerTeam}}
                <br>
                <br>
                <button ng-click="deleteListing(listing._id)">Remove</button>
                <button ng-click="addToCart(listing._id)">Add to cart</button>
                <button ng-click="showDetails(listing._id)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2">Details</button>
                </div>
        </div>
```

I am just having troubles figuring out what the button should do exactly. Is there a way to simply hard-code an input when the button is clicked? Will I need to write a new function to filter elements by sport type?